# Why value is different when called int main and in a class using inheritance C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Score{
public :
    int scoreA,Aopsi=0;
    void setAopsi(int a){
        this->Aopsi = a;
    }
    void goalA(int a){
        if (a==1)scoreA = scoreA + 1;
    }

};
class A_action: public Score{
public :
    int Akick(){
        int opsi;
        cout << "Team A Select where to kick : ";
        cin >> opsi;
        return opsi;
    }
};
 class A_after: public Score{
 public :
    int A_shot(){
        cout << Aopsi <<endl;
        int opsiA = 0; //i update the code for shorter code, so if goal opsiA = 1
        return opsiA; //opsiA and Aopsi is different        
    }
};

int main(){
Score s;
A_action a;
A_after A;
s.setAopsi(a.Akick());
cout << s.Aopsi <<endl;
s.goalA(A.A_shot());
}
```

I making some simple game about Penalty on Football
I have `Aopsi`. `Aopsi` is what player A chooses where to shoot or where to jump later.

Im set Aopsi on

```
 s.setAopsi(a.Akick());
```

then i call it
when Aopsi called in `main`, its replaced to what i set before.
But when i called in another class, value is not replaced.

for example,
A player choose 2, then Aopsi from 0 replaced to 2.
i try to cout it at `main` and on class `A_after` function `A_shot`.
Then the output is different.

`Aopsi` on `main` = 2

`Aopsi` on `A_shot` = 0

Should be

`Aopsi` on `main` = 2

`Aopsi` on `A_shot` = 2

I must using Inheritance.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Please post *only* the code that *doesn't* work and what you expect to happen.  Right now, your description and the code you posted is confusing.  You're mixing in things you say work, don't work, lines commented out and not commented out, etc.

Comment: You say you have "set Aopsi on `s.setAopsi(b.Bkick())`" but there is no such statement in the code you have shown.   Providing a [mcve] means providing code that other people can use to recreate the same problem you have.   You have not provided that, so nobody can help.

Comment: @FeiXiang ok i will try it

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie im really sorry, im will update it

Comment: @Peter my bad, s.setAopsi(a.Akick()) not s.setAopsi(b.Bkick())

Comment: Please don’t update with “what I wrote above is wrong, it should be this.” Just fix what you wrote so that is correct.

Comment: As others have mentioned, its impossible to know what's going on. For example, where's the definition of `Score::setScore()`?

Comment: @samuelnj setScore is ok, so i updated the code.

Comment: @DihyanFauzanaRosadi You'll have to give an example of what's going right and what's going wrong. Right now it's impossible to tell.

Comment: `scoreA` is uninitialized

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem you're having is that currently `Aopsi` is a member variable of the class that is unique to each instance you declare for the `Score` `A_action` and `A_after` classes. Since the way you've declared `Aopsi` makes it this way, it is perfectly valid behavior that you would get the result you describe because the `Aopsi` variable has been updated for the object `Score s` with the call `s.setAopsi(a.Akick());`. However, this call will not update the `Aopsi` variable of the `A_after A;` object as you think it should. To get that behavior, you will have to declare `Score` like this:

```
class Score{
public :
    int scoreA = 0;
    static int Aopsi = 0;
    void setAopsi(int a){
        this->Aopsi = a;
    }
    void goalA(int a){
        if (a==1)scoreA = scoreA + 1;
    }

};
```

This declares `Aopsi` as a static variable that is the same for all `Score` objects and classes that inherit it, giving you the behavior I believe you want.

Comment: It's unlikely that `static` is the right way to solve this problem.  Still, the OP would find it worthwhile to learn about.

Comment: @BenVoigt I totally agree with you, I think that a good approach would involved completely readjusting the structure of the classes themselves...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use inheritance for structuring sequences 
of related actions which share the state of the member aopsi. However you are using different instances of each Score derived class. That way, each instance will have its own, independent state.

You could keep your structure by making `A_after` derived from `A_action`, creating only the instance of `A_after a` and do all the actions on `a`.

```
a.setAopsi(a.Akick());
a.goalA(a.A_shot());
```

This you can do for each player. Make also sure to initialize `scoreA = 0` inside your class definition.

(Using static for aopsi won't work since then you can't set aopsi for each player).

Btw, avoid `using namespace std` in header files. C++ examples often use it to keep the code short (which is perfectly valid for short snippets that are not used elsewhere).